# How does an array recognize what to draw from itself by reading undefined parameter in function?

Tags: javascript

I just read an example in W3school. This function seems to know what these parameters(items, index) represent in the array. Why is that?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>List all array items, with keys and values:</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var fruits = ["apple", "orange", "cherry"];
fruits.forEach(myFunction);

function myFunction(item, index) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += index + ":" + item + "<br>"; 
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Result

```
List all array items, with keys and values:

0:apple
1:orange
2:cherry
```

Comment: item is the current array item, index is the current item index

Comment: Thank you. But if only one parameter is in the function, what does it refers to then? For Example, Array.from(items).forEach(function(item){
    var itemName = item.firstChild.textContent;
    if(itemName.toLowerCase().indexOf(text) != -1){
      item.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      item.style.display = 'none';
    }
  });
}

Comment: it's recommended to follow MDN JS tutorials https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: @ellie The parameters always form an ordered list. So, if you specify only a single argument, it will be the same as the first argument if you specify more than one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`forEach` works on an array, and takes a callback function that accepts three parameters: the first one is the current `item`, the second is the `index` of the current item, and the third is a reference to the array it was applied to.

In this example, `forEach` is iterating over `fruits` and applies `myFunction` as a callback.

Comment: In fact, it accepts three parameters: the third is the array on which it was called...

Comment: @FZs right. edited

Answer (score 1):

forEach takes a function as an argument,i.e a callback function. This callback takes upto three arguments.These are currentValue, index of the curernt value and the array forEach was called.
This is already predefined. You can look up at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

You as a programmer can now use this callback function to do some stuff on each of the element of the array.

Answer (score 0):

That's the job of `forEach`. It calls the function repeatedly, passing the value and index of each element of the array as arguments.

Comment: Shouldn't this be a comment and we close the question? I love your answers, but this doesn't belong here. :)